# Is there quick way to check user access using ALAssetsLibrary?

Tags: objective-c, ios, alassetslibrary

I think this is a really bad way to check user access to the resources.

**Is there better way to get user access?**

```
    ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
   // create library

    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        accessGiven = YES;
        return ;       
    };
    void (^assetGroupEnumberatorFailure)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error) { 
        accessGiven =  NO;
        return;
    };  

   // create 2 blocks 

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@" "];
    [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:assetGroupEnumberatorFailure]; 
  // use empty url to check acces..

    [library release];
```

Comment: Why do you think it is a bad way to check access? I am asking because it would help us provide suitable answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS **6.0** has better way to do that.

```
[ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
```

[Method Description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/ALAssetsLibrary/authorizationStatus)

[Authorization Status Enum](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/ALAuthorizationStatus)